# Azure media services on demand streaming from streaming origin without encoding

Tags: azure, media, azure-media-services

I want to encode my videos using ffmpeg and I create a 10MB MP4 file. Then I want to upload it on Azure media service as an asset. Then I want to stream it via Streaming Origin and apply CDN on that origin. I do not want to use ENCODING job from media services. So the problem is that after uploading an asset I see a URL which contains BLOB direct URL where I can stream. But I want to apply STREAMING Origin on this url without encoding job. Which I don't think is possible. What is the solution to that.

Here is the example

CASE 1 - Just uploaded and published
Let's say that I uploaded an mp4 file song on azure portal and i see the url like this
https://fiautomationblobstore.blob.core.windows.net/asset-ea4748ff-0300-80c3-1fe8-f1e525056262/_enr.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=6c0d7963-8eb9-4568-af27-454e1d09220e&sig=xP0xuk6BTh%2Bbrzgtur%2BJZypr%2FLE505%2Bp%2FQ3xB%2B%2Blj0E%3D&st=2015-07-08T00%3A12%3A06Z&se=2115-06-14T00%3A12%3A06Z
If I publish this it works but of course this is coming directly from the blob storage URL "fiautomationblobstore.blob.core.windows.net"

CASE 2 - uploaded and encoded and published
Where if I encoded another video then published the url was like this
http://tmediasvc.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/bcdcb0c3-c02a-4148-8e71-4d59caa5b205/enr.ism/Manifest
notice the "tmediasvc.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net" part its streaming origin.

How I can make first file coming from my streaming service "tmediasvc.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net" without applying ENCODING. I want to do this for 2 reasons.
1. I have applied encoding by ffmpeg before uploading
2. The size in second case grows from 16 MB to 100MB strangely. And this is because of very few options on media encoding in azure and i am not sure why there is no option for 360p/480p or less. its all above 720p which is weird. So encoding a file from 16BM to 100MB is Extremely wierd.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just uploading it to blob storage, then returning that URL? This way it will not apply any sort of formatting to the original file.

Or am I misunderstanding the question?